# Probability with a hundred coins

Tags: probability

I have a question.

If a Hundred coins are tossed at the same time what are the total number of possibilities, and what is the probability of getting tails on all the coins?

Could anyone answer it?

Thanks!

Comment: there are $2^{100}$ different outcomes of coin which result in $100$ different configurations. The probability of getting tails on all the coins is $1/2^{100} \sim 7 \cdot 10^{-31}$. It's *very* small

Comment: Why hundred? To develop some intuition do it with a very small amount of coins. Then project that on bigger or indeterminate amounts.

Comment: @Ant: $101$ different configurations

Comment: @Henry true that! thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could start with $N=3$ coins, instead of $100$, for instance.

For $3$ coins, the situation is simple to understand : you have $2$ possibilites for the first coin (head and tail), $2$ possibilites for the second coin, and $2$ possibilites for the third coin (these are supposed to be independant events). Then, you get $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 2^3 = 8$ possibilities. You can even do the list (H = head, T = tail) : $HHH, HHT, HTH, $ and so on.

For $N=3$, the probability of getting tails on all the coins is then $1/8$.

I hope you can "generalize" to $N=100$.

Comment: Starting with less coins is a good advice.

Answer (score 1):

Total ways are $2^{100}$ heads or tails for each coin and way where all are tails is $1$ so probability is $1/2^{100}$

Answer (score 1):

You can model the toss as a tupel with $100$ binary values, so there are $2^{100}$ possibilities. The sought chance is one of those $p=2^{-100}$.